# iOS & Android analytics viewing my app version install base

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, app-store, google-play-console

Is there a way to view what version of my app my users have installed - how many are on version 1.1 versus how many are on version 1.2?  I have looked for this on both iOS App console and Android Play Console but I have yet to find out the percentage of users still running older versions of my app.

I can see iPhone or Android OS versions, but not my app versions.

Answer (score 0):

In `Firebase Analytics` or `App+Web Analytics Property` you can use **App Version** dimension.